# Topology comparison method

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space,suppose $T:X \to X $ is a surjective continuous map, we have two metrics on $X$, that is :
\begin{align*}
 1- \rho(x,y) \qquad 2- \rho_{T}(x,y) := \sup \lbrace \rho(T^{n}(x) , T^{n}(y)) : n\geq0 \rbrace
\end{align*}
Now I'm going to show that the topology obtained from the metric $\rho_{T}$ is usually strictly coarser than the original $\rho$ topology, moreover :
\begin{align*}
\rho_{T}(x,y) = \max \lbrace \rho(x,y) , \rho_{T}(T(x),T(y)) \rbrace
\end{align*}
How could I do this ?

Comment: What does "usually coarser" mean?  Specifically, what does "usually" mean?

Comment: Well if $T$ is the identity then $\rho_T=\rho$, so "usually" can't mean "always".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I was reading that in a paper, when I saw that I got surprised too.

Comment: So is the purpose of your question to prove the equality $\rho_{T}(x,y) = \max \lbrace \rho(x,y) , \rho_{T}(T(x),T(y)) \rbrace$?

Comment: Yes It really is.

Comment: @Reza  Can you give a reference to the paper you alluded to?

Comment: It's this :
When is a transitive map chaotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a compact metric space, and suppose $T{\;:\,}X\to X$ is a continuous surjective map.

Define $\rho_T{\;:\,}X{\times}X\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\rho_T(x,y)=\sup \left\{\rho(T^{n}(x),T^{n}(y)){\,\mid\,}n\ge 0 \right\}$$
It's easily verified that $\rho_T$ is a metric on $X$.

Identically we have
\begin{align*}
\rho_T(x,y)
&=
\sup 
\left\{\rho(T^{n}(x),T^{n}(y)){\,\mid\,}n\ge 0 \right\}
\\[4pt]
&=
\max\left\{\strut\rho(T^{0}(x),T^{0}(y)),\,\sup \left\{\rho(T^{n}(x),T^{n}(y)){\,\mid\,}n\ge 1 \right\}\right\}\\[4pt]
&=
\max\left\{\rho(x,y)),\rho_T(T(x),T(y))\right\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Next, we compare the topologies of $(X,\rho)$ and  $(X,\rho_T)$ . . .

For $x\in X$ and $r > 0$, let
\begin{align*}
B(x,r)&=\{y\in X{\,\mid\,}\rho(x,y) < r\}\\[4pt]
B_T(x,r)&=\{y\in X{\,\mid\,}\rho_T(x,y) < r\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
By definition of $\rho_T$, we have $\rho_T(x,y)\ge\rho(T^{0}(x),T^{0}(y))=\rho(x,y)$.

Thus. $\rho_T(x,y) < r$ implies $\rho(x,y) < r$, hence $B_T(x,r)\subseteq B(x,r)$.

It follows that each open ball $B(x,r)$ of $(X,\rho)$ is a union of open balls of $(X,\rho_T)$, hence $B(x,r)$ is also open in $(X,\rho_T)$.

As a consequence, every open subset of $(X,\rho)$ is also an open subset of $(X,\rho_T)$.

Thus, the topology on $(X,\rho_T)$ is *finer* than the topology on $(X,\rho)$, but not necessarily strictly finer.

Suppose $T$ is such that $\rho(T(x),T(y))\le\rho(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Then $\rho_T=\rho$, so the topologies on $(X,\rho)$ and $(X,\rho_T)$ are the same.

For an example where the topologies on $(X,\rho)$ and $(X,\rho_T)$ are not the same, let $X=[0,1]$, let $\rho$ be the usual metric, and let $T{\;:\,}X\to X$ be the map $x\mapsto x^2$.

Then $(X,\rho)$ is connected, but $(X,\rho_T)$ is not connected since in $(X,\rho_T)$, the singleton set $\{1\}$ is clopen.